# Get minimum and maximum values from a list containing both strings and numbers in python and then replace the strings with these values?

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

As mentioned in the question, I have a list like this:

```
l = ['a', 'a', 'a', 200.0, 1.0, -55.4, 6.5, 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

and I want to get the `minimum` and the `maximum` values from that list in order to replace the strings 'a' with the `minimum` and 'b' with the `maximum`.
My output has to be like this:

```
l = [-55.4, -55.4, -55.4, 200.0, 1.0, -55.4, 6.5, 200.0, 200.0, 200.0]
```

I am able to achieve this goal by using a `while` loop to create another list to store only the numeric values, then sort this new list and pass the `minimum` value (as the `0th` element of this new list) to a variable and the `max` (as the last element) to another variable.

Since my list contains many more elements than the one I wrote as example, I'd like to know if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: More efficient than *what*, exactly?  Since you haven't posted your implementation, we have little way of knowing how efficient an algorithm you've used.  Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's not about the algorithm, in my opinion the method I described seems a little intricated and not very "pythonic"

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ["a", "a", "a", 200.0, 1.0, -55.4, 6.5, "b", "b", "b"]

mx = max((v for v in l if isinstance(v, float)))
mn = min((v for v in l if isinstance(v, float)))

out = [{"a": mn, "b": mx}.get(v, v) for v in l]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[-55.4, -55.4, -55.4, 200.0, 1.0, -55.4, 6.5, 200.0, 200.0, 200.0]
```